Issues formatting Excel from PowerShell
Long story short... I have a script that uses RESTful API to pull configuration information from an appliance. This script is relatively long, but the length is irrelevant.
The issue I'm having is that when I designed the script I wrote it in PS 5.1, everything worked fine in PS5.1. Now, trying to use the script in PS7 I'm encountering an issue with formatting the output.
I currently use COM objects to export to Excel and not the popular Import-Excel module. I wanted it to be standalone and note require an anything additional. Also, I didn't know that module existed when I wrote the script, and I didn't feel like redesigning the entire script.
Once I initialize the Excel workbook I move the active cell around and insert data as needed. All this works properly. The problem come in when trying to add cell borders.
If you test in PS5.1, you see it works perfectly, and in 7 you get an error about the border weight.
Aside from telling me to redesign the script and use Import-Excel, any help would be appreciated.
Here's a quick sample batch of commands to demonstrate. Obviously, this will require Excel to be installed on your system.
$Excel = new-object -comobject excel.application
$Excel.Visible = $true
$ExcelWorkBook = $Excel.Workbooks.Add()
$WorkSheetIndex = 1
$ExcelWorkSheet = $ExcelWorkBook.Worksheets.Item($WorkSheetIndex)

$ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item(1, 1) = "Test Data"

#Formatting shortcuts
$lineStyle = "microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlLineStyle" -as [type]
$borderWeight = "microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlBorderWeight" -as [type]

$objRange = $ExcelWorkSheet.UsedRange
$objRange.Borders.LineStyle = $lineStyle::xlNone
$objRange.Borders.weight = $borderWeight::xlThin
$ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item(1, 1).Font.Size = 16
$ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item(1, 1).Font.Bold = $True
[void] $objRange.EntireColumn.Autofit()

PowerShell 7 Error:
OperationStopped: C:\Work\Internal\GIT\Appliance_Administration\Excel_Test.ps1:15
Line |
  15 |  $objRange.Borders.weight = $borderWeight::xlThin
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Unable to set the Weight property of the Borders class



The core problem is that, for whatever reason, "microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlBorderWeight" -as [type] returns a reference to the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBorderWeight type in Windows PowerShell, but $null in PowerShell 7, so the line which is failing in PS7 is equivalent to $objRange.Borders.weight = $null. A quick and dirty workaround in lieu of an actual root cause would be to do something like this $XlBorderWeight_xlThin = 2; $objRange.Borders.weight = $XlBorderWeight_xlThin

GAC Woes
Expanding on comments, the core problem is that the expression "microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlBorderWeight" -as [type] is evaluating to $null in PowerShell Core.
As a result, $borderWeight is $null and this line:
$objRange.Borders.weight = $borderWeight::xlThin

is equivalent to
$objRange.Borders.weight = $null

By contrast, in Windows PowerShell the expression "microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlBorderWeight" -as [type] returns a reference to the xlBorderWeight type:
PS> $borderWeight = "microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlBorderWeight" -as [type]
PS> $borderweight

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     XlBorderWeight                           System.Enum

This is because Windows PowerShell searches the GAC for assemblies, but PowerShell Core doesn't:

Add-Type
In PowerShell 6 and higher, there is no GAC

Workaround
A quick and dirty fix is to use the constant values for the enums - e.g.
$XlBorderWeight_xlThin = 2;
...
$objRange.Borders.weight = $XlBorderWeight_xlThin

But note you've got the same problem with $lineStyle = "microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlLineStyle" -as [type], and with any other types defined in the Office Primary Interop Assemblies.
As an aside, it looks like $objRange.Borders.LineStyle = $null doesn't result in an error whereas $objRange.Borders.weight = $null does - \o/.
Add-Type
Alternatively, you can manually load the assemblies from the GAC yourself in PowerShell Core:
Add-Type -Path "C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll"

If you want to find the magic value for this path you can use Windows PowerShell 5.1:
PS> ("microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlLineStyle" -as [type]).Assembly.Location
C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll

You'll need to use the hard-coded path in PowerShell Core though.
Casting
That's not quite the whole story though because once the types are loaded you'll still get the same error, but for a different reason.
$objRange.Borders.weight is a Variant value - see:
PS> $objRange.Borders | gm

   TypeName: System.__ComObject#{00020854-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}

Name         MemberType Definition
----         ---------- ----------
... snip ...
Weight       Property   Variant Weight () {get} {set}

Windows PowerShell seems to be happy to convert a xlBorderWeight enum value to a Variant, but PowerShell Core doesn't so you'll have to do something like this instead to help it along by casting the enum to an int:
$objRange.Borders.weight = [int]$borderWeight::xlThin

Once you've done all of that  your code should finally work...

What an amazing answer!! Truly!! Thank you so much for the explanation. On the one hand it makes sense, but on the other hand, why would Microsoft have removed the GAC support by default in PS6+? Regardless, thanks again!

The GAC was a .Net Framework feature that didn’t carry over to the DotNet (Core) world - it was a way of sharing assemblies between applications in the days before package managers like nuget, which pretty much rendered it obsolete.
